# Increase all dates in a MySql database by a specified number of days

Tags: mysql

I want to increase all dates and timestamp entries in all tables in a MySql database by a specified number of days.

The database has a number of tables.

Ex (date):
If a date value in one of the table is 2016-12-24 and we specify 3 days then the solution should update the entry as 2016-12-27

Ex-2 (timestamp): for 2016-11-14 10:47:11  and we specify 3 days then the updated value should be 2016-11-17 10:47:11

Can this be achieved using a query or a stored procedure rather than writing update query for every table?

Answer (score 2):

update tables with below sql command to add days in date/datetime field :

```
UPDATE tableName SET `dateField` = DATE_ADD(`dateField` , INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the date_add function and include all updates in one procedure and execute it. The number of days to be incremented can be passed as input param to the proc!!